# Pip breaks when switch to Python3.7.9 using update-alternatives on Debian

Tags: debian, python3, pip

I am on Debian 11 which comes with python3.9. But I don't need it, I need python3.7. So, I installed pythonn3.7.9 and updated the alternatives.

The problem is that when I switch the python version to 3.7.9, I can't install anything using pip. I get the following error in `pip install` command:

```
sudo pip3 install requests
[sudo] password for deby: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
    from importlib.metadata import distribution
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 13, in <module>
    from importlib_metadata import distribution
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.3.4'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 15, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3261, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3245, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3274, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.3.4' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

But when I switch back to Python3.9 then Pip works. I don't know how to fix this. I looked it up on Google, but couldn't find an issue where anyone faced a similar problem.

[image]

Comment: I installed python3.7 later from tarball..i mean I created alternatives after googling it up.

Comment: No it's okay. I will switch to Python 3.8 then. Actually I want to install Modoboa on my server...it is not compatible with python3.9...so

Comment: @SulemanElahi if you switch to Python 3.8, don’t overwrite `/usr/bin/python3`; use a virtual environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib_metadata'` points to pip not being to able to locate the [importlib.metadata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) module which was added in Python 3.8 so pip from Debian repositories is not compatible with Python 3.7 you installed manually. You could install older version of pip manually, but I'd recommend using Python virtual environment which can also be set up [with different Python versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544).

So you can do something like

```
$ python3.7 -m venv python37
$ source python37/bin/activate
```

and work with the Python 3.7 version you installed without actually changing what `/usr/bin/python3` is system-wide and potentially breaking other things than pip.

Comment: +1. I’d add that users should *never* mess with the system Python (`/usr/bin/python3`), because Python-dependent packages rely on a certain version and setup of Python. The solution really is virtual environments.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it won't solve my problem.